# ClassNotFoundException: CompositeUriComponentsContributor when running in Jetty

Tags: java, spring, maven

I just started getting the below error when running a java spring webserver

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.web.method.support.CompositeUriComponentsContributor
```

This code was previously working and I didn't change any of the versions so I'm not sure what's going on. I have the following spring framework dependencies in my pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
<version>${springSecurity.version}</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
<version>${springSecurity.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
<version>${springSocial.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
<version>${springSocial.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
<version>${springSocial.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

with the versions been

```
<spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<springSocial.version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</springSocial.version>
<springSecurity.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</springSecurity.version>
```

This method is contained in the org.springframework spring-web jar so I also tried to use the maven dependency plugin to trace if some other dependency is loading an older version using the following cli argument

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=spring-web
```

However this is showing no results. I also tried some of the suggestions in this previous question [Using Maven: Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebDataBinderFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409769/using-maven-getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-b) but no luck.

The only other artifacts I have recently added to my pom are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
<version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
<artifactId>axis</artifactId>
<version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
<version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
<artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-api</artifactId>
<version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
<artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl</artifactId>
<version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
<artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-impl</artifactId>
<version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but I don't think these should be affecting spring-web dependencies. Has anyone come across this before or have any other ideas of what I could try to figure out what's going on?

Cheers,
Derm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of trial and error, adding in the below dependency seems to have fixed my issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Haven't been able to trace the dependency with CompositeUriConponentsContributor and spring-web but looks to have cleared the issue for me... In case anyone else comes across a similar problem

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE the following missing dependency resolved the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't have that dependency too.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason for that is your `spring.version` is below than `4.0.0.RELEASE`.`CompositeUriComponentsContributor` class can be found in spring web jar of spring 4.0.0.RELEASE. you can find the maven dependency for that jar [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/4.0.0.RELEASE).

Comment: Thanks Lakshman but I have also tried updating the Spring version but got the same error.